# ClickHouse Unique and Latest Value

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I am very new to database and its language.
Currently the company that I worked for have ClickHouse database.
I understand that the syntax is a bit different from sql.

I am trying to get the latest and unique value from different table.
I tried to write the following query but they are not working.

```
select
a.sku as SKU,
a.market as Country,
a.price,
b.currency as Currency,
b.commission_rate,
c.unit_cost,
a.status as Product_Status,
a.load_date
from a
left join b on a.sku=b.sku
left join c on a.sku=c.sku
where a.market ='CA' and b.currency='CAD' and a.status = 'Active'
order by a.load_date DESC
limit 1 by a.sku
```

SQL Error [241]: ClickHouse exception, code: 241,  Code: 241, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Memory limit (total) exceeded: would use 55.84 GiB (attempt to allocate chunk of 16777216 bytes), maximum: 55.83 GiB (version 21.5.6.6 (official build))

Below are the sample table

Basically, I am trying to get

latest active price by sku from table A

join by latest commission rate in table B

join by latest unit cost in table C

A

| sku | market | Price | status | load_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | CA | 21 | active | 21-2-2022 |
| bbb | CA | 22 | active | 21-2-2022 |
| ccc | US | 22 | active | 21-2-2022 |
| ddd | CA | 22 | inactive | 21-2-2022 |
| aaa | CA | 20 | inactive | 20-2-2022 |
| bbb | CA | 19 | active | 20-2-2022 |
| ccc | US | 19 | inactive | 20-2-2022 |
| ddd | CA | 19 | inactive | 20-2-2022 |

B

| end_date | sku | currency | commission rate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 21-3-2021 | aaa | CAD | 15% |
| 21-1-2021 | bbb | CAD | 15% |
| 21-2-2021 | ccc | USD | 20% |
| 21-5-2021 | ddd | CAD | 8% |
| 21-3-2022 | aaa | CAD | 30% |
| 21-1-2022 | bbb | CAD | 30% |
| 21-2-2022 | ccc | USD | 30% |
| 21-5-2022 | ddd | CAD | 30% |

C

| sku | last_po_date | unit_cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 21-3-2021 | 15 |
| bbb | 21-1-2021 | 20 |
| ccc | 21-2-2021 | 10 |
| ddd | 21-5-2021 | 5 |
| aaa | 21-3-2022 | 30 |
| bbb | 21-1-2022 | 30 |
| ccc | 21-2-2022 | 30 |
| ddd | 21-5-2022 | 30 |

Comment: It sounds to me like the record set you are trying to retrieve is too large to fit into memory.

Comment: yes, thats true.
because we have a new table append to the DB on a daily basic
if I cant get the unique and latest result, It could mean I am trying to get all the previous result which of course too large to retrieve and not very useful for me

Comment: The big problem is that you're not joining to the latest commission or unit cost. You're joining to all of them, and so they all fan out and make a huge result set.

Comment: whats the best way to select latest commission or unit cost then?

Answer (score 0):

Try these queries:

```sql
select 
    a.sku as SKU,
    a.market as Country,
    a.price,
    b.currency as Currency,
    b.commission_rate,
    c.unit_cost,
    a.status as Product_Status,
    a.load_date
from (
  select *
  from a
  where a.market ='CA' and a.status = 'Active'
  order by a.load_date DESC
  limit 1
  ) as a
left join b on a.sku=b.sku
left join c on a.sku=c.sku
where b.currency='CAD'

/* or try to test this one: */

select 
    a.sku as SKU,
    a.market as Country,
    a.price,
    b.currency as Currency,
    b.commission_rate,
    c.unit_cost,
    a.status as Product_Status,
    a.load_date
from c
RIGHT join (
  select *
  from a
  where a.market ='CA' and a.status = 'Active'
  order by a.load_date DESC
  limit 1
  ) as a on a.sku=c.sku
left join (
  select * 
  from b
  where b.currency='CAD'
  ) as b on a.sku=b.sku
```

Consider optimizing join-clauses follow these remarks:

- [Clickhouse: DB::Exception: Memory limit (for query) exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65317795/303298)
- [Clickhouse join with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64597112/303298)